# Is there a way to make JTextField for my address bar larger and curvier

Tags: java, javascript, css, swing, jframe

I'm making a browser just to practice my Java skills, is there a way to make my address bar which is a JTextField, larger instead of the swing's default value and also curvier. Here's my code.

```
//imports of the GUI 
//import java.awt.*;
 //import java.awt.event.*;
 //import javax.swing.*;
 //import javax.swing.event.*;
 //import javax.swing.text.*;
 //import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;

  //extends is to use the GUI class 
public class ReadFile extends JFrame {
private JTextField addressBar; //to have the address bar 
private JEditorPane display;  //display the html information
 //constructor 

//Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
public ReadFile() {
    super("SPHERE"); //name of the browser


    addressBar = new JTextField("enter an URL", 50); //inside the URL 
    addressBar.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                loadCrap(event.getActionCommand());
                }
}

    );
    add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);



    display = new JEditorPane();
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.addHyperlinkListener(
            new HyperlinkListener(){
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event){
            if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
            loadCrap(event.getURL().toString());

            }
            }
            } 
    );
    add(new JScrollPane(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(600,200);
    setVisible(true);

   }
  //load crap to display on the screen
    private void loadCrap(String userText){
    try{display.setPage(userText);
    addressBar.setText(userText);}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("crap!")}
    }



    }
```

I want to make a really usable browser, like I want the html and its' CSS pages to show, what else do I have to learn to make this work.

Comment: "curvier"? Please elaborate.

Comment: *"what else do I have to learn to make this work"* that Swing has limited support CSS and HTML and you should investigate an alternative solution to `JEditorPane`. You might like to also do some research into SwingLabs, SwingX `PromptSupport`

Comment: "I'm making a browser just to practice my Java skills"

Comment: If you look at chromes' omnibox, it's edges is curved. That's what I mean.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyone who answered my question, I really appreciated it. I learned a lot of new info.

Comment: @ReubenUkah Have you ever considered accepting MadProgrammer's answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Almost all of this comes down to manipulating the border, but this may not produce the results your after, for example...

[image: BigField]

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
field.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(field.getBorder(), new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0)));
```

Creating a rounded border is more difficult...

> and also curvier

There are a few ways you might achieve, this for example, you could create a `Border` of your own, for example...

```
public class RoundedBorder extends AbstractBorder {

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        insets.left = 5;
        insets.right = 5;
        insets.top = 5;
        insets.bottom = 5;

        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        RoundRectangle2D shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, 20, 20);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(shape);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Then apply it to your field...

```
field.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new RoundedBorder(), new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0)));
```

Which produces something like...

[image][image: Not Transparent]

But I don't like this, as, if you look closely, the area outside the border is still painted...You could have the border fill this area, but I like having the ability to provide transparent capabilities to components, so instead, you could fake it...

[image: Fake Border][image: Transparent field]

Basically, what this does is creates a custom component that can paint the around the field, but, because it can better control the painting process, can also provide transparency outside the border effect...

```
public class FakeRoundedBorder extends JPanel {

    private JTextField field;

    public FakeRoundedBorder(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        field.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(field);
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        RoundRectangle2D shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
        g2d.setColor(field.getBackground());
        g2d.fill(shape);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(shape);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

This is just a bunch of examples of course, you'll need to clean it up and provide customisation to the values yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "curvier". But here's a way to resize it and set the font:

```
    addressBar.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC, 30));
```

Comment: Don't screw with the preferred size of components, especially text components, this can truly screw up the UI.  Let the font change deal with it